# Android: can't create Bitmap with createBitmap method

Tags: android, graphics, bitmap

I'm fairly new to programming on the android platform. I'm having some problems massaging an int array to turn it into a Bitmap.

Each element in the int array is a number from 0 to 255, and represents a grey-scale pixel color (so 0 would be black, and 255 would be white, etc...). Here's my code:

```
int nPixels = 262144;
int width = 512;
int height = 512;
int[] converted = new int[nPixels];
int alpha = 255;
for (int i = 0; i < nPixels; i++) {
    //greyscale, so all r, g, and b have the same value
    converted[i] = (alpha << 24) | (pixels[i] << 16) | (pixels[i] << 8) | pixels[i];
}

Bitmap bm = Bitmap.createBitmap(converted, width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
```

The resulting bitmap has height and width of -1, which indicates that the createBitmap function didn't work. What is wrong with my method?

Oh, I took the shifting part for making the color from http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/graphics/CreateBitmap.html.

Edit: thought it might've been because alpha was 256 instead of 255, but I still get the same error.

Comment: Not quite clear on where the "colors" array is defined, I see a "converted" array, but not "colors".

Comment: oh sorry, that was from another part of the code that I just pasted there. `converted` = `colors`

Comment: Your code seems to run fine when I tested it.

Comment: What version of the SDK are you using? I'm using 2.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How do you learn that your Bitmap has [-1 -1] size? 
To get size, use:

```
int w = bm.getWidth();
int h = bm.getHeight();
```

This is working fine.

Comment: I'm using the debugger in Eclipse, and looking at the bitmap's mHeight and mWidth. It also won't show up in my view (but that could be another problem altogether).

Comment: I thought so. These are cached values, filled once you call mentioned methods.

Comment: Ah! So the bitmap actually worked? Only that the values aren't updated yet?

Comment: Seeing implementation of them gives you hint:

   public final int getWidth() {
      return mWidth == -1 ? mWidth = nativeWidth(mNativeBitmap) : mWidth;
   }

Comment: Right. Stupid question. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

I not sure if you can create the bitmap directly from the int array. You may need to iterate through the pixels of the bitmap and set the pixel value from the array using the bitmap setPixel method.

```
bitmap.setPixel (int x, int y, int color)
```

Comment: Of course it's possible to create Bitmap from array of pixels.