# Android byte array to Bitmap How to

Tags: android, bitmap

How can I convert byte array received using socket.

1. The C++ client send image data which is of type uchar.
2. At the android side I am receiving this uchar array as byte[] which is ranges from -128 to +127.

What I wanted to do is that receives this data and display it. For that I was trying to convert to Bitmap using `BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray()`, but no luck I am getting null Bitmap. Am I doing right or any other method available.

Thanks in advance....

Comment: Are you sure you're getting a non-null byte array? Snippets may help.

Comment: Yes I am getting byte array which is ranging from -128 to 127

Comment: It looks like your image cannot be decoded. Is there an offset (because of headers, most likely) you need to go to for actual image data?

Comment: Actually I am sending image from OpenCV which is array of uchar representing RGB pixel value, there is no header, only pixel value.

Comment: So the receiving image should be bitmap ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've been using it like below in one of my projects and so far it's been pretty solid. I'm not sure how picky it is as far as it not being compressed as a PNG though.

```
byte[] bytesImage;
Bitmap bmpOld;   // Contains original Bitmap
Bitmap bmpNew;

ByteArrayOutputStream baoStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bmpOld.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, baoStream);
bytesImage = baoStream.toByteArray();
bmpNew = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytesImage, 0, bytesImage.length);
```

edit: I've adapted the code from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7802707/android-cant-create-bitmap-with-createbitmap-method) to use RGB, so the code below should work for you. I haven't had a chance to test it yet so it may need some adjusting.

```
Byte[] bytesImage = {0,1,2, 0,1,2, 0,1,2, 0,1,2};
int intByteCount = bytesImage.length;
int[] intColors = new int[intByteCount / 3];
int intWidth = 2;
int intHeight = 2;
final int intAlpha = 255;
if ((intByteCount / 3) != (intWidth * intHeight)) {
    throw new ArrayStoreException();
}
for (int intIndex = 0; intIndex < intByteCount - 2; intIndex = intIndex + 3) {
    intColors[intIndex / 3] = (intAlpha << 24) | (bytesImage[intIndex] << 16) | (bytesImage[intIndex + 1] << 8) | bytesImage[intIndex + 2];
}
Bitmap bmpImage = Bitmap.createBitmap(intColors, intWidth, intHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer...Actually my client sending uchar array representing RGB pixel value. There is no header. Does that cause problem

Comment: You'll probably need to recreate it manually. There are a few [examples here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1143293/how-to-convert-array-of-bytes-into-image-in-java-se) that should work for you though.

Comment: But I found that ImageIO is not supported in Android SDK here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5311163/how-to-load-bufferedimage-in-android

Comment: [Bitmap.createBitmap()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#createBitmap%28int[],%20int,%20int,%20android.graphics.Bitmap.Config%29) sounds like what you need then. I think android stores bitmaps as byte arrays internally so I'm sure there has to be some easy way to convert it.

Answer (score 10):

From the comments to the answers above, it seems like you want to create a Bitmap object from a stream of RGB values, not from any image format like PNG or JPEG.

This probably means that you know the image size already. In this case, you could do something like this:

```
byte[] rgbData = ... // From your server
int nrOfPixels = rgbData.length / 3; // Three bytes per pixel.
int pixels[] = new int[nrOfPixels];
for(int i = 0; i < nrOfPixels; i++) {
   int r = data[3*i];
   int g = data[3*i + 1];
   int b = data[3*i + 2];
   pixels[i] = Color.rgb(r,g,b);
}
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(pixels, width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
InputStream is = new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openStream();
byte[] colors = IOUtils.toByteArray(is);
int nrOfPixels = colors.length / 3; // Three bytes per pixel.
int pixels[] = new int[nrOfPixels];
    for(int i = 0; i < nrOfPixels; i++) {
        int r = (int)(0xFF & colors[3*i]);
        int g = (int)(0xFF & colors[3*i+1]);
        int b = (int)(0xFF & colors[3*i+2]);
        pixels[i] = Color.rgb(r,g,b);
 }
imageBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(pixels, width, height,Bitmap.Config.ARGB_4444);
     bmImage.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap );
```