# Please somebody tell me how to create a bitmap out of this?

Tags: android, bitmap, decode, bitmapfactory

Im building an app, which makes it possible to up and download image files.
Im receiving an inputstream from a server when i ask for image files. if i call the method just after i uploaded the picture without closing my app first, its possible to decode the stream to a bitmap and everything works fine.

But if i close first, i doesn't work and the content looks different.
the string i get looks like "{"Attachment":"/9j/4S5RXhp....."

Comment: Annika, not getting your question properly, can you please explain in simple language?

Comment: its fine when i send the request just after i took a picture and then uploaded the image file with my app. im having troubles when i take a picture, upload it and then close my app to start it again and request the image file ive uploaded before.  i get the skimage decoder returned null error everytime when trying to parse to a bitmap allthough it works fine in the other case. i decoded it to a string and found out that the string i get in the second case looks totally different just like described above

Comment: That means, first you upload image to server and then you close the app and then again you open the app and trying to get that images?

Comment: yes, and the problem i have i that i just cant find out why i cant decode it.

Comment: can you please post your image url here, which you are getting from server?

Comment: http://postimg.org/image/pe72lehgz/ does not work

Comment: This image url is not proper. Its damaged, please check that you uploading image proper and you getting image proper.

Comment: everything is fine http://postimg.org/image/lstbw34ad/

Comment: no, if everything is fine then you getting wrong url, because its not full url, image url must have its extension with it like, postimg.org/image/pe72lehgz.jpg

Comment: i do not have an url i make a connection with, im using third party library and the api documentation is bad

Comment: my question is how to create a bitmap out of this http://postimg.org/image/pe72lehgz  it must be possible somehow

Comment: visit this links may be it will useful to you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18630080/android-byte-array-to-bitmap-how-to

Comment: now i dont get any error but when i want to display it, there is no picture

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
            BufferedReader streamReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8"));
            StringBuilder responseStrBuilder = new StringBuilder();

            String inputStr;
            while ((inputStr = streamReader.readLine()) != null)
                responseStrBuilder.append(inputStr);

            JSONObject att = new JSONObject(responseStrBuilder.toString());

            byte[] bytes = Base64.decode(att.getString("Attachment"), Base64.DEFAULT);
            bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
```