# android asynchronous image loading from database byte[]

Tags: java, android, asynchronous

I have beeen following this tutorial: [Click Me](http://www.technotalkative.com/android-asynchronous-image-loading-in-listview/)

The problem is that I have my images in byte[] in my database, I don't have the links for each image. 
The tutorial works great. But i don't know my url image because I use byte[] to store the data, so:
**How can I convert the urls to byte[] using asynchronous?**

I don't put my code because is the same like the tutorial! But if your like, let me know

Thanks for helping me!

Answer (score 1):

The tutorial loads image from the `String` urls. Since you do not have image URLs and you are saving images in your database as `byte[]` so you need to render images from `byte[]`. So, instead of loading images from URL, you can load `byte[]` to create a Bitmap. This is the code that can convert `byte[]` to bitmap.

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baoStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bmpOld.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, baoStream);
bytesImage = baoStream.toByteArray();
bmpNew = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytesImage, 0, bytesImage.length);
```

This code is taken from [Android byte array to Bitmap How to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18630080/android-byte-array-to-bitmap-how-to#answer-18630561)

And yes, definitely, you will have to modify implementation of `MemoryCache` and and `ImageLoader` accordingly as well.

Comment: So, i have to change everything. Some another tutorial to do what I want?